# ¿Por qué este XPath no devuelve nada?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

Estoy utilizando scrapy en una p'agina d Amazon de las laptops que mas se han vendido

Quiero Seleccionar el precio y el producto, por ejemplo de este framgmento de HTML

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=<a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="/Apple-MacBook-13-inch-256GB-Storage/dp/B0863D4XJW/ref=zg_bs_565108_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=XGMP498DGDMYEQ4GX0HW">
        <span class="a-color-secondary">2 offers from <span class="a-size-base a-color-price">
            <span class='p13n-sc-price' >$979.00</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
</span>
</div>
</span>
</li>
<li class="zg-item-immersion" role="gridcell">
    <span class="a-list-item">
        <div class="a-section a-spacing-none aok-relative">
            <div class="a-row a-spacing-none aok-inline-block">
                <span class="a-size-small aok-float-left zg-badge-body zg-badge-color">
                    <span class="zg-badge-text">#2</span>
                </span>
                <span class="aok-float-left zg-badge-triangle zg-badge-color">

                </span>
            </div>
            <span class="aok-inline-block zg-item">
                <a class="a-link-normal" href="/Acer-Flagship-CB3-532-Premium-Chromebook/dp/B06XD3LXXK/ref=zg_bs_565108_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=XGMP498DGDMYEQ4GX0HW">
                    <span class="zg-text-center-align">
                        <div class="a-section a-spacing-small">
                            <img alt="(Renewed) Acer Flagship CB3-532 15.6 inches HD Premium Chromebook - Intel Dual-Core Celeron N3060 up to 2.48GH.z, 2GB RAM, 16GB SSD, Wireless AC, HDMI, USB 3.0, Webcam, Chrome OS" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51840t%2BtcFL._AC_UL200_SR200,200_.jpg" height="200" width="200">
                        </div>
                    </span>
        <div class="p13n-sc-truncate p13n-sc-line-clamp-2" aria-hidden="true" data-rows="2">
            (Renewed) Acer Flagship CB3-532 15.6 inches HD Premium Chromebook - Intel Dual-Core Celeron N3060 up to 2.48GH.z, 2GB RAM, 16GB SSD, Wireless AC, HDMI, USB 3.0, Webcam, Chrome OS
        </div>
    </a>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
```

lei la documentacion de la pagina **https://devhints.io/xpath** y encontre que puede obtener de esta forma el precio :

```
./div[@class="p13-sc-truncate p13-sc-line-clamp-2"]/text()
```

y el producto con sus caracteristicas:

```
./spam[@class="p13n-sc-price"]/text()
```

(puedo estar equivocado claro, y haber malentendido de alguna forma el articulo)

el codigo que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amazon"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [

            'https://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/electronics/565108?ref_=Oct_s9_apbd_obs_hd_bw_b2N0e_S&pf_rd_r=5WY8SVEKCHZKM8YHZXQW&pf_rd_p=079802f4-7ae7-5199-a84a-6dbb4331abf2&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-11&pf_rd_t=BROWSE&pf_rd_i=565108'

        ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        '''
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'amazonBestLaptops-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
        '''

        SET_SELECTOR = '.set'
        for amazon_info in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):


            PRICE_SELECTOR = './div[@class="p13-sc-truncate p13-sc-line-clamp-2"]/text()'
            PRODUCT_SELECTOR = './spam[@class="p13n-sc-price"]/text()'

            yield {

                'product': amazon_info.xpath(PRODUCT_SELECTOR),
                'price': amazon_info.xpath(PRICE_SELECTOR),

            }
```

y el error que estoy obteniendo(porque no estoy obteniendo lo que se supone:)

```
D:\maykel\computacion\scrapy\amazonLaptopsBest\amazonLaptopsBest\spiders>scrapy runspider amazon_spyder.py
2020-05-11 20:57:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.1.0 started (bot: amazonLaptopsBest)
2020-05-11 20:57:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-05-11 20:57:12 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-05-11 20:57:12 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'amazonLaptopsBest',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'amazonLaptopsBest.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['amazonLaptopsBest.spiders']}
2020-05-11 20:57:12 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: e701d9bca26e2f99
2020-05-11 20:57:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-05-11 20:57:13 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-05-11 20:57:13 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-05-11 20:57:13 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-05-11 20:57:13 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-05-11 20:57:13 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-05-11 20:57:13 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-05-11 20:57:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-05-11 20:57:14 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/electronics/565108?ref_=Oct_s9_apbd_obs_hd_bw_b2N0e_S&pf_rd_r=5WY8SVEKCHZKM8YHZXQW&pf_rd_p=079802f4-7ae7-5199-a84a-6dbb4331abf2&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-11&pf_rd_t=BROWSE&pf_rd_i=565108> (failed 1 times): 503 Service Unavailable
2020-05-11 20:57:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/electronics/565108?ref_=Oct_s9_apbd_obs_hd_bw_b2N0e_S&pf_rd_r=5WY8SVEKCHZKM8YHZXQW&pf_rd_p=079802f4-7ae7-5199-a84a-6dbb4331abf2&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-11&pf_rd_t=BROWSE&pf_rd_i=565108> (referer: None)
2020-05-11 20:57:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-05-11 20:57:15 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1058,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 48322,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/503': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.011807,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 12, 0, 57, 15, 691287),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'retry/count': 1,
 'retry/reason_count/503 Service Unavailable': 1,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 12, 0, 57, 13, 679480)}
2020-05-11 20:57:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

me pueden ayudar
imagino que sean lso xpath que no estan bien implementados y no obtienen lo que deseo,por ejemplo:

```
$979.00

(Renewed) Acer Flagship CB3-532 15.6 inches HD Premium Chromebook - Intel Dual-Core Celeron N3060 up to 2.48GH.z, 2GB RAM, 16GB SSD, Wireless AC, HDMI, USB 3.0, Webcam, Chrome OS
```

y asi sucesivamente

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Termine instalando una extension --> https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/xpath_finder/--y ahora obuve ambos xpath ...sin embargo, sigo sin obtener el resultado deseado..Las direcciones que obtuve fueron estas: 
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/ol/li[1]/span/div/span/a[1]/div   y
   
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/ol/li[1]/span/div/span/a[2]/span/span/span

Answer (score 0):

Creo que quiere la informacion de cada producto

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "amazon"

def start_requests(self):
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/electronics/565108?ref_=Oct_s9_apbd_obs_hd_bw_b2N0e_S&pf_rd_r=5WY8SVEKCHZKM8YHZXQW&pf_rd_p=079802f4-7ae7-5199-a84a-6dbb4331abf2&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-11&pf_rd_t=BROWSE&pf_rd_i=565108'
    ]
    for url in start_urls:
        print("Start Url ", url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    '''
    page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    filename = 'amazonBestLaptops-%s.html' % page
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
    '''
    all_computers = response.xpath('//span/a[@class="a-link-normal"]/@href').getall()
    for laptop in all_computers:
        # no esta la url completa
        laptop = 'https://www.amazon.com' +laptop
        print("enlace:\t", laptop)
        yield scrapy.Request(laptop, callback=self.parse_detalle)

def parse_detalle(self, response):
    print("entra equipo")
    NAME_SELECTOR = 'span#productTitle::text' # css UNICO
    PRICE_SELECTOR = 'span#priceblock_ourprice::text' # css UNICO
    CAPACITY_SELECTOR = "//label[@class='a-form-label']/following-sibling::span[1]/text()" # XPath
    COLOR_SELECTOR = 'div#variation_color_name>div>span::text' # este no
    CONFIG_SELECTOR = 'div#variation_configuration>div>span::text' # este no
    yield {
        'NAME_SELECTOR': response.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        'PRICE_SELECTOR': response.css(PRICE_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        'CAPACITY_SELECTOR': response.xpath(CAPACITY_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        'COLOR_SELECTOR': response.css(COLOR_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        'CONFIG_SELECTOR': response.css(CONFIG_SELECTOR).extract_first(),

    }
```

Como veras trae

```
{'NAME_SELECTOR': '\n                \n                    \n                    \n                \n\n                \n                    \n                    \n                        (Renewed )Samsung Chromebook XE303C12-A01 11.6-inch, Exynos 5250, 2GB RAM, 16GB SSD, Silver\n                    \n                \n\n                \n                    \n                    \n                \n            ', 'PRICE_SELECTOR': '$180.00', 'CAPACITY_SELECTOR': 'Silver', 'COLOR_SELECTOR': 'Silver', 'CONFIG_SELECTOR': None}
```

Ahora estoy trabajando en scrapy pero aqui me complico un poco con los texto de cada cosa AMAZON le pone mucho a su sitio, espero puedes **sustituir los xpath** y lo de pasar de pagina tenia el codigo pero ahora mismo no lo encuentro

Comment: Ten cuidado de ser baneado del sitio. puedes usar una extension como XPath Helper (Chrome) o Ruto x-path Finder (Fire Fox)

Comment: A que se refiere Cristian con esto: Ten cuidado de ser baneado del sitio...Si estoy haciendo indevido por favor, hagamelo saber

Comment: por otra parte sigo queriendo saber como obtener la informacion de una etiqueta con una clase unica, como la quepuse en mi ejemplo que no me funciona

Comment: pues algunos sitios te bloquean porque si bien no es ilegal tampoco lo ven con buenos ojos y te bloquean el acceso por unos dias o puede que un mes, no eh sabido que sea mas. Con respecto a lo de las clases unicas pues hacer lo como el de **PRECIO** usando el css, no suelo usar lo porque es el mas propenso a cambiar, eliminas estilo antes que el maquetado. Espero haber despejado tus dudas

Comment: gracias..sin embargo, como lo harias. ayudame a obtener ese conocimiento

Comment: **edite** un poco la respuesta y pues soy malo explicando pero con CSS es parecido a poner estilo en una pag. y en XPath recorres los elementos del HTML y usando las clases en lugar del ID, o [corchetes] si hay elementos anidados algo como `div[@class="section"/p[2]/text()]` para este emmet `div.section>p*2` donde el texto que quieres esta en el 2do parrafo

Comment: la pregunta ya tiene toda la informacion necesaria, solo quiero saber como usted obtendria el precio y marca del modelo de la web que puse..porque y o ponga la direccion y no la obtengo, solo eso